# Motion of Particle Pushed By Flow of Liquid

Tags: classical-mechanics

If I were to slide an ice hockey puck into a constant headwind, the puck would slow down and start sliding back towards me.  If it continued past me and beyond, it would reach a terminal velocity matching the headwind.  Originally I thought the headwind represented a constant force, but it can't do if there is a terminal velocity.

Can anyone tell me please what the formulation is for this kind of motion?  It feels something like a negative linear function of momentum, but I can't it out!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is a constant force, opposed by a friction force which depends on velocity. At terminal velocity the two forces are equal. It is the same equation of motion as throwing a ball up in the air under gravity (the wind replaces gravity and ice friction replaces air resistance).

Comment: It is the same as air resistance after a Galilean change of coordinates (i.e., $x\mapsto x+v_{wind}t$ so the wind speed = 0).  So $F\propto v$ at low speed but $F\propto v^2$ at high speed.

Comment: @Paul What if there was no friction from the ice? Then it can't be a constant force because a constant force would mean the puck accelerates indefinitely.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks but do you know what the formula for displacement from the starting position could be in this case?  If a particle is projected at 10 m/s into a headwind of -10 m/s?  The formulae $F\propto v$ and $F\propto v^2$ aren't going to work once the puck has started moving back towards me in the direction of the headwind.

Comment: Change your Galilean inertial frame so you are projecting the particle 20 m/s into no wind.  Now 20m/s is quite high speed so $F\propto v^2$ is appropriate for the air resistance it encounters.

Comment: @user10354138 I'm sorry, but that doesn't make sense. If the puck is moving at -9 m/s and the now tailwind is at -10 m/s then how can it be exerting an ever increasing force is there is to eventually be a terminal velocity?

Comment: @user10354138 Is it the case that if the puck is moving at -9 m/s and the tailwind is -10 m/s, then the force is proportional to the difference in these velocities, and hence is quite small, and this explains why we would reach a terminal velocity?

Comment: I suppose that when the puck is moving at the same speed as the wind then the wind is exerting no force. Think of puck and wind as a single object.

Comment: @Paul I think I got the answer. The force is proportional to the difference between the velocities. So if you slide a puck at 100 m/s into a headwind of 10 m/s, the displacement x(t) is the solution of the equation x''(t) = k(10 - x'(t)), x(0) = 0, x'(0) = -100  The 10 - x'(t) is always positive because x'(t) < 10  When you solve this you get the graph you would expect with the oblique asymptote.  Thanks for your ideas that pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @user10354138 I think I got the answer. The force is proportional to the difference between the velocities. So if you slide a puck at 100 m/s into a headwind of 10 m/s, the displacement x(t) is the solution of the equation x''(t) = k(10 - x'(t)), x(0) = 0, x'(0) = -100  The 10 - x'(t) is always positive because x'(t) < 10  When you solve this you get the graph you would expect with the oblique asymptote.  Thanks for your ideas that pointed me in the right direction.